# How to read a PDF file in android application without Intent

Tags: android, pdf

I am going to read a pdf file from my sdcard and load it into my android application without starting any pdf reader installed on my android device!

is it possible?
how?

thanks!

Comment: By *loading into your application* do you mean for displaying or do you mean for UI-less processing?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the .pdf can be read with read with the iText library for Android http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg But If you want see the content you need a pdf viewer app or integrate one in your app

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have access to internet, just upload it to Google Drive and view it online.
Just you need a Browser in this case.